# ArrayList with HashMap Vs ArrayList with Class

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist, hashmap

I want to use some set of data from `ArrayList`. I have 2 approach for storing data in `ArrayList`.

**1st Approach :**

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> showList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

and Where `HashMap` structure is

```
 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
 map.put("title","Mytitle");
 map.put("Description", "MyDescription for show");
```

**2nd Approach:**

```
private ArrayList<DataProvider> showList = new ArrayList<DataProvider>();
```

and the DataProvider is

```
public class DataProvider{
public String title = "";
public String description = "";

public void setTitle(String mTit){
    title = mTit;
}

public void setDescription(String mDec){
    description = mDec;
}public String getTitle(){
    return title ;
}public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}
```

I know how to store and retrieve the data form **ArrayList**. I want to know which one will perform **better** and **faster**.

Comment: From the context, for readability and misc, it looks like alternative 2 is much better. Looks like you are hacking OOP on the #1. Though Data Provider is still a bad name..

Comment: 2nd Approach is better and faster

Comment: `private List<DataProvider> showList = new ArrayList<DataProvider>();` is the better approach

Comment: I think it depends on how you want to retrieve the data. If you want to get a provider with a particular title first approach is faster (almost O(1)) where as second one needs iteration and comparison. However insertion is costly in case of first approach. So if you are going to do frequent searches over the list go with approach #1 else choose #2.

Comment: @NinadPingale Faster? Really? I thought the first one would be faster as in the second one you would have to create all these wrapper instances too.

Comment: @1337 And the Maps inside the ArrayList? You create instances of these as well. And they probably create instances of some other objects inside of them (depending of the implementation).

Comment: @Yuvaraja: how many objects are you dealing with? 'Faster' in what terms: reading (randomly, sequentially) or writing? 'Better' is vary vague - you need to specify what is better for you. However, if you are just talking about read/write speed why not create a (unit)-test and find out?

Comment: @maslan Right, right. It's morning, forgive me ;) Need some coffee.

Comment: Creating classes to describe objects is the natural way of how to program in Java. That’s why it is called an object oriented programming language. You should have strong reasons before deciding to replace the natural Java OO approach with a `Map` based one (when creating a Java program).

Answer (score 1):

If Your data has a constant set of fields, it is obvious, that DataProvider approach is faster, since (even though rather quick) getting an object from a Map involves some search. For a map of size two it is rather insignificant. The Map approach will also use a bit more of memory (allocation of additional objects, and fields in a Map implementation)

However if You have objects such as i.e. Products in a store, You might have a different set of properties, like some products might have color, some weigth, ant this is where a Map might be usefull.

You might also consider using different implementation of List depending of what will You want to do with the List for most of the time (alot of insertions/deletions/or just getting objects by their position in list).

Comment: Yes you are right, if you do more insertion/deletion you should prefer LinkedList instead of ArrayList but if you just use the list as a readonly like get data, it is better to use ArrayList because of random accessabilty performance against LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

Second Approach is better that the first one .For More clarity you can refer

[The Map Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

[The List Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) and[The Set Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)

Think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To check out it's `SPEED` practically, I taken out time differences -

```
public class Test
{

    private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> showList1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private static ArrayList<DataProvider> showList2 = new ArrayList<DataProvider>();

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {

      Date a1=new Date();


      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
      map.put("title","Mytitle");
      map.put("Description", "MyDescription for show");

      showList1.add(map);

      Date a2=new Date();

      System.out.println(a2.getTime()-a1.getTime());


      Date b1=new Date();
      DataProvider dataProvider=new DataProvider();
      dataProvider.setTitle("Mytitle");
      dataProvider.setDescription("MyDescription for show");
      showList2.add(dataProvider);

      Date b2=new Date();

      System.out.println(b2.getTime()-b1.getTime());
    }
}

class DataProvider{

    public String title = "";
    public String description = "";

    public void setTitle(String mTit){
        title = mTit;
    }
    public void setDescription(String mDec){
        description = mDec;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title ;
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }
}
```

Output -

```
0
0
```